# relative font size

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to build an element inside a div container by using simple append function as follow

```
$("#container").append("<label style='font-size:100%;'>ASAD</label>");
```

now I am using the same thing to append the same element to main page body but I am getting size of both font sizes same. That is one inside the div and the body one. What I want is to get size relative to the div when appending to div.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is the problem? Maybe some demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "font-size: 1em"? ems are also a unit of relative measurement. 1em means the same size as the parent element.

Comment: no i have not. I though percentage would be good for relative size.

Comment: em means width of capital `M` letter in the typeface specified by parent element, not the same size!

Comment: Typographically, yes, em's refer to the capital M. However, in CSS,  an em is a unit of relative measurement. "1em" in terms of CSS, will result in the element taking on the font size of it's parent.

Comment: @alirana — In CSS, for font-sizes, 100% and 1em are equivalent.

Comment: @chipcullen, in CSS [em unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#em-unit) *Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.*, so yes technically it's will be same size as parent, but to be same size as parent you may skip it at all, not specifying `font-size` property is the same as using `font-size` equal to `1em` or `100%`.

Comment: @JuicyScripter — Assuming that no rule-set has a selector matching the element and setting a size already.

Answer (score 0):

The em size unit is recommended by the W3C. 1em is equal to the current font size. The default text size in browsers is 16px. So, the default size of 1em is 16px.

The size can be calculated from pixels to em using this formula: pixels/16=em

```
h1 {font-size:2.5em;} /* 40px/16=2.5em */
h2 {font-size:1.875em;} /* 30px/16=1.875em */
p {font-size:0.875em;} /* 14px/16=0.875em */
```

How to Size Text in CSS
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

Comment: very much confused...what i want is like when we give a div inside another and give it 100% width it is relative to the container div.And if we copy paste the same child div to body it will be 100% width according to body. I want some thing like this hope u understand

Comment: i am confused too, what does "relative font size" has to do with div tags?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is by using the **relative font units** like **em** or **rem**. The **em** font unit depends on **the font size of the container**, while the **rem** unit depends of the **root element font size**.

For example, you could set the container div to have a font size of 16px and setting the font size of any of the child elements with the **em** unit will make it relative to the container div.

```
div { font-size: 16px }

div>p  {
  font-size: 1.5em; //this will be equal to 24px
}
```

On the **p** element, **1em is equal to 16px**, which means that **1.5em will be equal to 24px**.

There is a great article written here https://kolosek.com/css-relative-font-size/, that explains the relative font sizes in detail.